# set object-level permissions in django 3.0

Tags: python, django, django-cms

let's say i have a model with a cms placeholder:

```
class Content(models.Model):
    placeholder = PlaceholderField('placeholder')
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and i want to make the placeholder frontend-editable, depending upon whether it is published.  i.e. i want it editable through the frontend so long as it is unpublished, but once a placeholder has been published, i want it to be non-editable.

i've tried the following in admin.py:

```
class ContentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj.published:
            return False
        else:
            return True

admin.site.register(Content, ContentAdmin)
```

but there doesnt seem to be any effect.  i've also tried using a custom backend.

```
def has_perm(self, user_obj, perm, obj=None):
        if isinstance(obj, Content):
            if obj.published:
                return False
            else:    
                return True
        return False
```

also, no effect.  i'm not getting any errors, but the placeholder continues to render as editable. what am i doing wrong? i'm currently testing with the admin, is it simply that i can't deny the superuser permissions?

using django 1.6.1 and django-cms 3.0.12

thanks!

Comment: I've rolled back your question and deleted my incorrect answer. Hopefully some can answer your question.

Comment: Why not override your model's `save()` method, check for the published value and bail on the save if the instance is published?

Comment: they would still be able to open the plugin for editing, but when they clicked 'save' nothing would happen? i think that would be very confusing for the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `get_readonly_fields` in `ContentAdmin` to check if your Content object has been published and set `placeholder` to read-only accordingly.

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    if obj and obj.published:
        return ('placeholder')
    return ()
```

**UPDATE**:

The admin `readonly` only affects Django admin.

You can [override the model's `save` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) and check if `placeholder` is one of the update fields. If it is and the `Content` instance is published, it will do nothing.

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
             update_fields=None):
    if self.published and 'placeholder' in update_fields:
        return
    super(Content, self).save(force_insert=force_insert,
        force_update=force_update, using=using, update_fields=update_fields)
```

This will ignore any new value provided to `placeholder` field in the front-end.

On the front-end, you can leave it as is with only this change. (The field will still show as editable, although the edits will make no difference).

Otherwise, you can modify the `render_placeholder` (which I am assuming is a custom tag) to check the published field of the `Content` object and set the input you are rendering as `disabled`.

It will look something like this

```
{% if obj.published %}
    Placeholder: <input disabled type="text" name="placeholder">
{% else %}
    Placeholder <input type="text" name="placeholder">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: just tried this, and it doesn't work, the placeholder is still editable.  i didn't mention that the placeholder is outside the cms, rendered using `{% render_placeholder content.placeholder %}.  should that matter?

Comment: @ericwerfel Yes it does make a difference, check my updated answer.

Comment: {% render_placeholder %} is not a custom tag, and 'placeholder' is a Django PlaceholderField object, not the name of an input. http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/how_to/placeholders.html

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot about django-cms. In this case you might have to write some JavaScript that disables those specific placeholder fields on load. Or don't show the placeholder if content is published.

Comment: is there a way to show the content in the placeholder without showing the placeholder?

Comment: `{{ obj.placeholder.placeholder }}` or `{{ obj.placeholder }}` (where obj is `Content` object). I'm not sure if that will work though.